# Woocommerce custom_fields(Shipping and Billing) in email_order_meta_fields

Tags: woocommerce, checkout, custom-fields

I'm trying to store custom shipping and billing fields in order and then to be print in emails ( admin & customer ) but with no success , is there anyone with big heart to help me  ?
So as you can see i removed some fields , added other fields in Shipping & Billing then i try  to store data of order and at the last i try to send my extra fields in order_email .
Here is my code in functions.php

```
// Replace billing_email with shipping_email  " This because custome don recieve email notification if don't ask invoice "
    add_action('woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'set_billing_email_from_shipping_email', 50, 2 );
                function set_billing_email_from_shipping_email( $order_id, $data ) {
                    // Get customer shipping email
                    $email = get_post_meta( $order_id, '_shipping_email', true );
                
                    // Set billing email from shipping email
                    update_post_meta( $order_id, '_billing_email', $email );
        
        } 
// Remove fields
  add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'wc_remove_checkout_fields' );
            function wc_remove_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
    
                // Billing fields
                    unset( $fields['billing']['billing_first_name'] );
                    unset( $fields['billing']['billing_last_name'] );
                    unset( $fields['billing']['billing_address_2'] );
                    
    
                // Shipping fields
                    unset( $fields['shipping']['shipping_address_2'] );
                    unset( $fields['shipping']['shipping_company'] );
    
                // Order fields
                unset( $fields['order']['order_comments'] );
    
                return $fields;
    }       


   //Add custom fields
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_shipping_fields' , 'custom_shipping_fields' );
            function custom_shipping_fields( $fields ) {
                $fields['shipping_email'] = array(
                    'label'         => __( 'Email', 'woocommerce' ),
                    'required'      =>true,
                    'class'         => array( 'form-row-last' ),
                    'validate'      => array( 'email' ),
                ); 
                $fields['shipping_phone'] = array(
                    'label'         => __( 'Telefono', 'woocommerce' ),
                    'required'      => true, 
                    'class'         => array( 'form-row-first' ),  
                    'clear'         => true,
                    'validate'      => array( 'phone' ),
                );
                $fields['shipping_invoice'] =array(
                    'type'          => 'checkbox',
                    'class'         => array('form-row-four'),
                    'label'         => __(' Fattura ?'),
                    'label_class'   => array('woocommerce-form__label l_checkbox'),
                    'input_class'   => array('woocommerce-form__input woocommerce-form__input-checkbox i_checkbox'),
                    );
        return $fields;
    }
    
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_billing_fields' , 'custom_billing_fields' );
            function custom_billing_fields( $fields ) {
                $fields['billing_vat'] = array(
                    'label'         => __( 'P.Iva/CF', 'woocommerce' ),
                    'required'      =>false,
                    'class'         => array( 'form-row-last' ),
                ); 
                
        return $fields;
    };

    function custom_shipping_save_extra_checkout_fields( $order_id, $posted ){
        if( isset( $posted['custom_shipping_fields'] ) ) {
            update_post_meta( $order_id, '_custom_shipping_fields', sanitize_text_field( $posted['_custom_shipping_fields'] ) );
        }
    }

    function custom_billing_save_extra_checkout_fields( $order_id, $posted ){
        if( isset( $posted['custom_shipping_fields'] ) ) {
            update_post_meta( $order_id, '_custom_shipping_fields', sanitize_text_field( $posted['_custom_shipping_fields'] ) );
        }
    }
    add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'custom_save_extra_checkout_fields', 10, 2 );
    
    function custom_email_order_meta_fields( $fields, $sent_to_admin, $order ) {
        $fields['custom_shipping_fields'] = array(
                    'label' => __( 'Custom Siping Fields' ),
                    'value' => get_post_meta( $order->id, '_custom_shipping_fields', true ),
                );
        return $fields;
    }
    add_filter('woocommerce_email_order_meta_fields', 'custom_email_order_meta_fields', 10, 3 );
```

Thank you!